# How to get save file dialog as a control in windows forms

Tags: c#

Working with windows forms, programmatically clicked a "Save File" button which opens save file dialog.

How can I access this save file dialog ? Eg, to put the location, filename etc

Is there any way to get the save file dialog which is already opened, like we do with forms Application.OpenForms

Comment: You mean like settting it up before show? Where is the problem? `var dialog = new Whatever();` then `dialog.SomeProp = "SomeValue";` then `dialog.ShowModal();` ?

Comment: No, I mean as wo do Application.OpenForms, we will be able to see all opened forms and get into them, find controls and do what we want. So can we do the same with save file dialog ? Which gets opened by clicking the button.

Comment: It doesn't makes sens ... seems like XY problem ... why on FSM sake you wana iterate opened dialogs? you put location and filename BEFORE you show it ... also when dialog is shown UI thread is blocked anyway

Comment: Okay, So if we have attached process with an application and we have a button to click programmatically ? And which is save file dialog button of course, do you mean we won't have access to this dialog then ?

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: I think, Seems like getting handler to save file dialog window, which is opened on button click of an application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get SaveFileDialog as a control, but there is a way you can access the "Save As" window and access the informations you want.

Using hwnd - window handle. OR handle to a window.

Here is how you can get the window, if your save file dialog is at the front, you can use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]   
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public static string GetActiveWindowTitle(IntPtr handle)
{
  const int nChars = 256;
  StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

  if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
  {
    return Buff.ToString();
  }
  return null;
}

public static void YourMethod()
{
  IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
  var name = GetActiveWindowTitle(handle);

  if (handle != IntPtr.Zero && name == "Save As")
  {
   // Do your work here
  }
}
```

Further, you can go inside child windows and access the information like FileName, Save button and so on...

For ex, if you want to access Save button, add following in existing

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr handleParent, IntPtr handleChild, string className, string WindowName);
```

The Class name of Save button would be "**Button**"

And you can get the handle to this button using following:

```
IntPtr edithWnd = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save");
```

Where,
handle - immediate parent handle

"Button" - class name

"&Save" - caption of button window...

Hope this will help!!

Comment: This is the thing I wanted!!!.... Milestone!!  I have been trying to get the solution and started with window handle as well but I was far away and this one brings me at front!!

Answer (score -2):

The answer to your question is pretty easy! `System.Windows.Forms` got a form just for that the `SaveFileDialog Class`.

Official Documentation: [SaveFileDialog Class (System.Windows.Form)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: We can do this, but what if we have attached process with an application and we have a button to click programmatically ? And which is save file dialog button of course

Comment: Is the application a C# application? Is it coded by you?

Comment: No, its a commercial application - encompass

Comment: Um... that makes it harder. I know within your OWN application you can assign a SaveFileDialog to a button. Now however from another application, that changes everything. What does the application do exactly? How is it launched?

Comment: We can easily do attach to process in VS and do some plugin kind of things and get into that

Comment: Ah yes, that's right! That could work indeed, haven't coded in VS in a long time... (Been coding in C++ lately.) so I cannot further help you with that!